# Reload current page with different parameters

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to reload the current page by passing parameters to javascript and calling location.href.

```
function setEventListener(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {

        let sortColumn = item.parentElement.getAttribute('data-sortColumn');
        let sortOrder = item.getAttribute('data-sortOrder');
        let controller = item.getAttribute('data-controller')

        let hostName = window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port;
        let url = new URL(hostName + controller + sortColumn + '/' + sortOrder + '/');
        location.href = url.href;
    }
```

The url is good, I can grab it from console output and paste in to the window and load the page fine. But this just calls the click function and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to add the transfer protocol

```js
item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let sortColumn = item.parentElement.getAttribute("data-sortColumn");
    let sortOrder = item.getAttribute("data-sortOrder");
    let controller = item.getAttribute("data-controller");

    let hostName = window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port;
    let url = new URL(
      location.protocol + "//" + hostName + "/" + controller + sortColumn + "/" + sortOrder + "/"
    );
    location.href = url.href;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might default that for some reason, now I just need to figure out why it duplicates the attributes in the url on subsequent clicks.